# How to specify the relative path in such a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project with a parent pom with two children pom:

```
de-service . (root pom)
de-service-api (child pom)
de-service-web  (child pom)
```

In the root pom, I have:

```
 <modules>
        <module>de-service-api</module>
        <module>de-service-web</module>
    </modules>
```

Under de-service-web's resources/model directory, I have a file which I need to load:

```
testModel.model
```

And I specify its relative path as (modelName):

```
de-service-web/src/main/resources/model/testModel.model
```

Then I have code to load this file:

```
  try {
                SerializedClassifier model = new SerializedClassifier();
                model.setModelFile(new File(modelName));
                return model;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This works on my local computer, but once it's deployed on my remote server, it reports an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/admin/de-service-web/src/main/resources/model/testModel.model
```

It looks like the full path name formed from the relative path lacks a level of the root directory, which is the root of the parent pom.xml:
de-service.

The relative path is relative to the root of the "de-service-web", not the real root of the project 'de-service'. How to specify the relative path in this a project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you are using a Maven project, then everything inside the `resources` folder should be made available on the classpath, at the root of the classpath.  Here is one way to load your file:

```
String fileName = "model/testModel.model";

try {
    ClassLoader classLoader = YourClass.class.getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
    SerializedClassifier model = new SerializedClassifier();
    model.setModelFile(file);
    return model;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this doesn't work, then you should check the classpath of your WAR/JAR to make sure that `testModel.model` is in fact available.

Comment: I am doing this in a static method and it complains that 'getClass()' is not a static method and can't be used in a static environment.

Comment: @user697911 Just use `YourClass.class` to get the class loader in the case of a static method which has no instance.

Comment: You should use getResourcesAsStream ( "/model/testModel.model") and do not use File access which will not really inside a packaged jar later...